# SSISDB too large

Tags: ssis, etl

I have client whose SSISDB is too large (71GB). I have tried to set RETENTION_WINDOW to 50 from 365 and ran the maintenance job, but it has made little difference. Can someone please suggest an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done database and log backups? Then if you want to shrink the database or log files you should be able to if there is free space.